# I get "list assignment index out of range" error

Tags: python, list

I get "list assignment index out of range" error . The strange thing with this error is not every iteration I get this. I have "n" iterations in my code, sometimes it works well and I get no error, sometimes 4th iteration, 10th iteration, 12th iteration ...randomly I get this error.

What I do in my code is:
I have a case based reasoning function which works for 4 independent variables (Xs) and 1 dependent variable (Y). There are weights in CBR function, namely w1, w2, w3 and w4. I am trying to optimize these weights to get minimum MAPE % error with a genetic algorithm. Genetic algorithm part of the code is below:

```
iteration=25
t=0
while t<iteration:
    def calculate_fitness (w1,w2,w3,w4):
        fitness_score=1/CBR (w1,w2,w3,w4,X_train,y_train) #fitness function %MAPE
        #print(w1,w2,w3,w4,a)
        return fitness_score
    #print(calculate_fitness (new_population[0][0],new_population[0][1],new_population[0][2],new_population[0][3]))



    total=[]
    for i in range (len(new_population)):
        y=[]
        y.append(new_population[i][0])
        y.append(new_population[i][1])
        y.append(new_population[i][2])
        y.append(new_population[i][3])
        y.append(calculate_fitness(new_population[i][0],new_population[i][1],new_population[i][2],new_population[i][3]))
        total.append(y)
    total=sorted(total, key=lambda x: x[4], reverse=True)    

   # print('ILK POP')
    #for i in range(len(total)):
     #   print(total[i])




    #print('New',new_generation)


    ########roulettewheel selection#############
    sum_of_fitness=0
    for i in range (len(new_population)):
        sum_of_fitness=total[i][4]+sum_of_fitness
    probability=0
    probability_list=[]
    for i in range(len(new_population)):
        probability=total[i][4]/sum_of_fitness+probability
        probability_list.append(probability)

    def find_index(probability_list):
        p = random.uniform(0,1)
        index=0
        for i in range (len(probability_list)):
            if p <= probability_list[i]:
                index=i
                break
            else :
                index=0 
        #print(index)
        return (index)

    def crossover (a,b):
        a1 = a[:]
        b1 = b[:]
        crossover_point=random.randint(0,3)
        for i in range(crossover_point):
            a1[i], b1[i] = b1[i], a1[i]

        return [a1, b1]

    def mutation (a):
        gen_place=random.randint(0,3)
        a[gen_place]=random.uniform(0,1)
        return (a)

    #NEW GENERATION

    #New Generation   ELİTİST STRATEGY %10
    new_generation=[]

    for i in range (elitism_number):
        new_generation.append(total[i])


    for i in range(int(crossover_number/2)):
        a= find_index (probability_list)
        b=find_index (probability_list)
        c=crossover(total[a],total[b])
        new_generation.append(c[0])
        new_generation.append(c[1])

    for i in range (mutation_number):
        a=find_index(probability_list)

        new_generation.append(mutation(total[a]))

    
   # print('BEFORE:',new_generation)
    
    
    def correct_populations (new_generation):
        
        for i in range(len(new_generation)):
            total_gene=new_generation[i][0]+new_generation[i][1]+new_generation[i][2]+new_generation[i][3]
            new_generation[i][0]=new_generation[i][0]/total_gene
            new_generation[i][1]=new_generation[i][1]/total_gene
            new_generation[i][2]=new_generation[i][2]/total_gene
            new_generation[i][3]=new_generation[i][3]/total_gene
            
        for row in new_generation:
            del row[4]
        return (new_generation)
    
    correct_populations(new_generation) ########gene total must be 1
    
    
    
        
                    
   # print(new_generation)
    
                                                          
        
    del total
    del probability_list
    del new_population
    del y
    
    
    new_population=copy.deepcopy(new_generation)
    
    new_generation.clear()
    
    
    print (t)
    print('BEST:',new_population[0])
    print('Best Value %:', 1/(calculate_fitness(new_population[0][0],new_population[0][1],new_population[0][2],new_population[0][3])))
    #print(probability_list)
    t=t+1

print ("Finished!")
'''
```

I get this error in this part :

```
for row in new_generation:
            del row[4]
```

please help me to figure out whats happening in here?
Thanks

Comment: deleting element inside a for loop when you are traversing the same list is bad bad idea.

Comment: That just mean the list has size 4 or lower, just print each row before the del, and you'll see when the erro occurs the row juste befoe. You may leanr to debug yourself. When there is an error about a variable, print it, print all the parts of the statement just before it occurs to ensure it does what you think

Comment: any suggestion instead of using del in a for loop?

Comment: You should show that you have imported random module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use error handling in this part of code to run it smoothly.

```
for row in new_generation:
    try:
            del row[4]
    except:
            return new_generation
return new_generation
```

Comment: What does this code do exactly? It works smooth with no error.